How can I keep a main IK control from "popping off" a rig?
I would like the control bone to be firmly attached to the end of the chain, rather than flying off when I move it too far away.
Video of the issue: https://i.imgur.com/iuCSQ3O.mp4

I'm not sure that this is possible as it would create a circular dependency if you make the target follow the Ik bone
